# How to apply a formula on a rage "A3:A"?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to copy the same formula to all cells in the range `"A3:A"`.

Do I have to use Apps script or can this be done via the UI?

[image]

Comment: can you show an example via a demo spreadsheet? see [mcve] and [ask] this question is quite ambiguous thus runs the risk of being closed.

Comment: Added a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an Arrayformula. You can see the documentation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en).

For example:`=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A+B1:B)`

This will add each value in A to each value in B like A1+B1, A2+B2, A3+B3, and so on.

If you post the formula you are trying to use, I may be able to adapt it using `Arrayformula`.

Comment: Thanks, that a long formula: `=if(Input!A10=TRUE, SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($M$2 , Q5, Placements!A3),Q6, REGEXREPLACE(Placements!C3, "\s", "")),Q7,Placements!D3),Q8 ,Placements!K3),Q9, Input!I10),Q10, Input!J10), Q11, Input!L10), "")`

Comment: Yea, that is very long. Could you possible share a version of your spreadsheet, without sensitive data?

Comment: Added a link. I'm interested in dynamically expanding the Impression pixel column in "3Pas" tab, to to as many rows that will be added in the future. Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PbSJ09kcs7wqdOpgKVp8mXJZm2SO8kky/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try this: =ARRAYFORMULA(if(Input!A10:A=TRUE, SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(M3:M , Q5, Placements!A3:A),Q6, REGEXREPLACE(Placements!C3:C, "\s", "")),Q7,Placements!D3:D),Q8 ,Placements!K3:K),Q9, Input!I10:I),Q10, Input!J10:J), Q11, Input!L10:L), ""))